# spring-boot error in thymleaf with js scripts

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I included .css and .js in my thymleaf like this :

```
<script src="/javascript/one.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/two.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/three.js"></script>
```

this error showing up in console

```
2016-07-24 21:08:05 WARN  PageNotFound:1149 - No mapping found for HTTP request with         URI [/javascript/one.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-07-24 21:08:05 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:997 - Successfully completed request
```

i dont know where i am missing

Comment: Where did you add the Javascript files in your Spring Boot project? They are normally in `src/main/resources/static/`. Things should work if you have them in a sub-directory `javascript` there.

Answer (score 1):

in thymleaf you need add javascript source folder like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/javascript/one.js}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/javascript/two.js}"></script>
```